# Difference between sampling distribution and data distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study

I went to a stats course refresher last week and the instructor talked about data distribution and sampling distribution. I am just practicing with the exercises shown in class.
Based on my dataset below, 
For the data in Week2, what can I explain about the ‘data distribution’. and the ‘sampling distribution’ of the sample mean?
I would appreciate any explanation of these two terms. Thanks

```
fishy <- structure(list(week1 = c(2.011, 1.994, 10.332, 7.056, 4.926,
                                  6.12, 2.039, 5.948, 7.731, 8.41, 
                                  11.055, 7.157, 5.855, 25.243,
                                  36.553, 76.281, 38.902, 64.689, 42.934, 
                                  80.373, 115.858, 145.981,84.735, 
                                  163.084, 190.472, 295.79, 254.71, 
                                  273.446, 582.495),
                       week2 = c(535.013, 513.534, 824.442, 1130.764, 
                                 1396.367, 1122.016, 1263.061, 1449.587,   
                                 1588.527, 680.99, 1861.677, 1432.656, 
                                 2921.025, 3595.931, 2071.98, 1666.726, 
                                 1594.989, 1522.255, 2496.464, 2169.722, 
                                 1870.255, 1039.203, 54.847, 0.266, 60.603,
                                 601.822, 244.916, 124.749, 74.059)), 
                      .Names = c("week1", "week2"), class = "data.frame", 
                      row.names = c(NA, -29L))
boxplot(fishy,week1~week2)
```

Comment: Your quotation marks are ambiguous: I'm pretty sure the two concepts you want to distinguish are "data distribution" and "sampling distribution of the sample mean."

Comment: If you remember your last course, then maybe useful indicators for characterizing the empirical distribution, such as *central tendency*, *variance* or *scale*, and *shape*, might be a good start. The second question about sampling distribution of the mean has already been addressed elsewhere on this site.

Answer (score 4):

Data distribution is the distribution of the observations in your data (for example: the scores of students taking statistics course).

Sampling distribution of the sample mean: Let imagine you sample the data from population n times (randomly, each sample has N observations), for each sample you compute the mean. So you have n means of n samples. Then you have the distribution of the sample mean.

Hope it's easy to understand.